# How to get ERRORLEVEL in return of a WMIC remote command execution?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command-prompt, wmic, errorlevel

I am executing a WMIC command on a remote system. Just to make it fail-safe, I want to check the ERRORLEVEL after calling, but it doesn't seem to retrieve that.

I tried the below command:

`wmic /node:IP_ADDR /user:"DOMAIN\USER" /password:"****" process call create "cmd.exe /c INVALID_PATH"`

The console output I got is:

```
Executing (Win32_Process)->Create() 
Method execution successful. 
Out Parameters: instance of __PARAMETERS
{
        ProcessId = 5600;
        ReturnValue = 0;
};
```

And, checking **ERRORLEVEL** after this also gives **0**.

How can I evaluate that my command has executed successfully?

**EDIT1:**
As per the comments I would like to give more details about the issue.

I am trying to run a bat file that contains a simple script of copying files and I have explicitly given the wrong path as below:

`copy "C:\INVALID_PATH\test.bat" "VALID_PATH" /y`

`exit /b %ERRORLEVEL%`

Executing this bat on the same machine gives **1** as ERRORLEVEL. But executing this through WMIC gives below output:

```
Executing (Win32_Process)->Create()
Method execution successful.
Out Parameters:
instance of __PARAMETERS
{
        ProcessId = 6492;
        ReturnValue = 0;
};
```

And **ERROROLEVEL** is still **0**. I tried with passing the copy command directly, but the result is the same.
How can I validate that the command has executed successfully?

Comment: It says it succeeded so technically it would've succeded the wmic command but not the one inside it. Try `"cmd.exe /c INVALID_PATH || exit /b 1"` so it will exit with an exit code of 1 which would become the return value (I think) but I don't know if it would translate to the errorlevel. Try it out and see what it does.

Comment: Currently you seem to be expecting an errorlevel from the verb `call` to return the errorlevel from an internal `cmd.exe` command. In addition to that, `INVALID_PATH`, is not technically a command, but simply a path. I must assume therefore that you're trying to run an executable file on a target PC and wanting to know if it was successfully executed? or completed?. Please [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62513474/edit) to provide a complete and properly explained question, showing the code you've used to retrieve the value you're looking for, not the value you're not!

Comment: You cannot get errorlevel with this call. You successfully started CMD so you got 0 for that. _Returns an integer value of 0 if the process was successfully created_ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/create-method-in-class-win32-process.

Comment: @Compo I have provided some more details about the issue. Please have a look. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately though you've not understood the previous comments, the error level you are getting, is the return code from the WMIC Call verb, it will never return the error code from the result of an internal `copy` command within the called cmd.exe process.